# How do I use if else function through radio button in html.erb view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, radio-button, erb

I have a view like this (/app/views/projects/new.html.erb)
how should I use if else function to do this?

```
<p>
<%= f.label :payment_type, "payment_type" %>
<%= f.radio_button :payment_type, 1, checked: true %>(1)
<%= f.radio_button :payment_type, 2 %>(2)
</p>

if payment_type == 1

  show these things

else(or payment_type == 2)

  show these things

end
```

my controller save this views(/app/controllers/projects_controller.rb):

```
def new
  @project = Project.new
end

def create
  @project = Project.new(params.permit![:project])
end
```

how do I use it property

Comment: You need to do this using javascript by taking the payment_type value and passing it to a JS function and put the if and else cases in there. Can you explain in your question what should be the show these things part in the if condition?

Comment: Complete your `html.erb` with your form for you not provide the whole form tag, don't know what's the `f` are. And is `payment_type` a attribute of `@project`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Javascript**

You'll need to use Javascript to give you some front-end interactivity.

To give you some specifics - when you run a Rails application, the *rails" part of the system will run in the backend -- meaning that each time you render an "view", your controller is going to pull the data from your model, allowing Rails to create a pure HTML output for you.

The issue you have is that when you render this output, you cannot then invoke Rails functionality again for that call (look up how [`stateless`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) technology works -- `An example of a stateless protocol is HTTP, meaning that each request message can be understood in isolation.`), meaning you need some way to manage the front-end area of your interface.

This is done with [Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript):

> [Javascript] is most commonly used as part of web browsers, whose
>   implementations allow client-side scripts to interact with the user,
>   control the browser, communicate asynchronously, and alter the
>   document content that is displayed

--

This is how you'll handle it:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u0hbLmp4/4/)

> 1. "Bind" the radio inputs to a "change" event
> 2. When the change event is triggered, perform the business logic directly in your JS
> 3. Append the changes to the view ([DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model))

---

**Rails**

Here's what you'll need to do specifically:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", 'input[type="radio"]', function(){
    if($(this).val = "1") { 
        // something here
    }else{
        // something else here
    };
});

#app/views/controller/your_view.html.erb
<%= f.label :payment_type, "payment_type" %>
<%= f.radio_button :payment_type, 1, checked: true %>(1)
<%= f.radio_button :payment_type, 2 %>(2)
```

--

**Ajax**

Further to this - if you wanted to return Rails-based business logic to your view, you'll want to use `ajax`. I won't go into too much detail with this, apart from saying that this will essentially send a "pseudo request" to your browser.

Here's how you'd set it up:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :payments do
   get :type, on: :collection #-> domain.com/payments/type
end
```

This custom method will allow you to perform the business logic you need:

```
#app/controllers/payments_controller.rb
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
   def type
      type = params[:type]
      if type == "1"
         ...
      else
         ...
      end
   end
end
```

This will then give you the ability to crate an ajax call to this method:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", 'input[type="radio"]', function(){
        $.ajax({
           url: "payments/type",
           data: { type: $(this).val() },
           success: function(data) {
              alert("Success");
           }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<% if payment_type == 1  %>
    these
<% else %>
   those
<% end %>
```

Comment: it shows `undefined local variable or method 'payment_type'`

Comment: you have to provide the variable through your controller; if its a property of your model, as it looks, you could try @mymodel.payment_type

Comment: how should I do this?
could you please do an example for me?

Comment: please edit your question to add your controller code for this view first: which controller is serving this view?

Comment: if @project has a member 'payment_type', then you could do `<% if @project.payment_type ==1 %>` and the rest stays the same